# In the US, can a senator get a prisoner out?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction, us-senate

In the latest TV series [Scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandal_(TV_series)) episode, "Get Out of Jail, Free", Olivia asks Mellie, a senator from Virginia, to release a prisoner imprisoned in Virginia, assuring that this is within her powers. I know this is just a TV series and even she might mean she has powerful friends or non-lawful tricks, but out of curiosity, is that possible or is there anything in US constitution or US law that let a senator get a prisoner out??

FYI, the senator did get two prisoners out, one imprisoned for embezzlement and another one for killing a president's son (and is put in Supermax!)

Comment: It would be a scandal (and the end of the career of the senator) if word got out about that abuse of power...

Answer (score 5):

No a senator does not have that power under their elected position. However politics does not work like that. A senator could know the governor of their state very well. Governors could issue pardons which will release people from jail. Governors can also command a certain person to do something, like release a prisoner.

Comment: Ditto for the President of the United States.

Comment: Yes as an aside the President does not have the authority to release prisoners held under the authority of a state of the United States. However the president can enforce federal judicial writs, subpoena state prisoners, and other procedures which could result in the release of a state prisoner.

Comment: This actually recently occurred in California when Arnold was exiting.  He signed a pardon for the son of a politician he had dealings with.  He even made some interesting comments after the fact.  http://articles.latimes.com/2011/jan/03/local/la-me-arnold-pardons-20110103

Comment: The legislature can also pass a "private bill" in the Congress and most states that can apply to just on prisoner (in a prison it has jurisdiction over).